# Avoid a duplicate value when I update array using $push on MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I want to push some values into array using Python.
Maybe next time when i update the array ,it will insert some values exists ,so it will got some duplicate values.
I want to know is there anyway to avoid duplicate values.
Should I use db.collection.find() to determine whether I should insert or not ?

```
db.graph.insert_one({"user_id": a.url}, )
for j in a.followers:
    db.graph.update({"user_id": a.url}, {"$push": {"following": j.url}})
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The best way to do this is using [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)  operator which ensures that there are no duplicate items added to the set and the [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) modifier  to add multiple values to the"following" array.

```
urls = [j.url for j in a.followers]
db.graph.update_one({"user_id": a.url}, {"$addToSet": {"following": {"$each": urls}}})
```

also you should use the [`update_one`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) method because `update` is deprecated.

Comment: is it possible with findOneAndUpdate ?

Comment: how do you remove ?

Comment: Just a side note, this might work well for the example in question - with primitive value types (string, integer) - but might not work well with arrays containing documents. In such a case, comparison done for the whole document and checks if existing documents have the same properties, exactly in the same order and exactly the same values. Meaning, you can't use some unique property of document in an array.

Answer (score 6):

I think, that you can use $addToSet operator: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Comment: Try to give an example, rather than just a URL.  That way, answers aren't reliant on URLs remaining valid.